# How to convert an Access database to SQL?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, phpmyadmin

I want to convert my Access database to SQL because my host only supports importing a database through SQL in their phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, I don't think Access has the ability to generate SQL for creating its tables and data.  What I can suggest is importing it into SQL Server (any version should do) and then use SQL Server to generate the create table and data scripts.

Answer (score 3):

Download something like SQL Server 2005 Express, which is free to use, and import it into there, then generate the SQL

http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/express.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Because DB on your server is MySQL, I would:

1. install MySql on local machine
2. connect ODBC to MySQL DB
3. from access open MySQL database (as ODBC resource) and copy data to it
4. export data from MySQL

It's long way round, but it's most likely to work properly.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [Bullzip Access To MySQL](http://www.bullzip.com/products/a2m/info.php) on two separate projects and found it to be quite solid and reliable.

Comment: That app is good, I've lost almost a week to find a way to convert access db to sql query. @John, you must try there is Access to MsSQL and Access to MySQL

Answer (score 1):

What version of Access are you using? You will need to export all the Access tables to CSV files and import each one into mySQL. There might be tools that automatically do that now, but they could screw up your data or ay PK and FK mappings you have. Best way IMO to do it table-by-table to ensure data integrity.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean MySQL? Which is a database implementation.
'SQL' is a language used for querying and modifying relational databases. Microsoft Access supports the SQL language. Like most stnadards, the SQL standard has different implementations on different database systems!

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the best way to do this is a combination of some/most of the posted answers.

download an express version of SQL server and get it running on your PC.
download SSMA (SQL Server Migration Assistant) from 
http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/product-info/migration.aspx

this handles the various changes to datatypes that you may/may not require.

then once thats migrated everything over you'll be free to connect to your SQL server epxress instance from phpMyAdmin

I'm actually doing some contract work atm migrating Access DB's to SQL and this is the route I took and found it to be very straight forward and robust

Answer (score 0):

You may like to give a try to the migration tool(http://support.microsoft.com/kb/237980)